# lombok @Value @NonFinal inheritance

Tags: java, lombok

I'm trying to chain several @Value @NonFinal classes without creating any constructors.

Expecting that lombok chooses to generate a constructor that call super with all the arguments that match.

Is there any way of achieving this? It seems to break with an error that doesn't make sense because the father class have such constructor given by the annotation. I tried this with classes in different files, same behaviour.

Example:

```
public class TestLombok {

@Value
@NonFinal
class A {
    @NonNull Integer a;
}

@Value
@NonFinal
class B extends A {
    String b;
}

}
```

Error:(12, 5) java: constructor A in class TestLombok.A cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.Integer
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.

Finding out what fields or methods a parent class has requires resolution. The moment lombok needs to generate methods, resolution is not possible, since it would change the outcome of the available fields and methods.

Disclosure: I am a lombok developer.

Comment: Thanks Roel! Can you tell if there is any plan to support this with additional annotations or should I just accept the additional boilerplate?

Comment: I ended up ditching class inheritance in favour of interfaces to make the project Lombok friendly for immutable DTOs, overall things look cleaner on my case.